# Convert diary entries to org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, diary

Is it possible to convert an emacs diary file to an org-mode file? I know that I can use `(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)` to see the diary in org-agenda but I want to have the events in an org file, ideally as a date tree, so that I can edit them, add notes, tags, etc.

Comment: Each `org-mode`  entry can take the form of a custom sexp, such as `* My Task` new line `SCHEDULED: <%%(my-custom-function date)>`  See the manual faq page and search for the word sexp:  https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html  A custom function can also match against a list of dates ... instead of having one function per date ...

Comment: I think the [this](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+emacs/org/README.html#agenda-recommendations) section of the Spacemacs documentation might be helpful for you...